# a class for a parser.. in the same way that class Regex is for regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I find the class Regex in .net extremely useful (for both matching and matching/replacing).
There are some patterns that cannot be specified in regular expressions, but rather need a little grammar. Is there a library for parsers that DO NOT require code generation (like ANTLR)... but where I can specify the syntax in my code on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be useful to understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you wanting to declare your grammar at runtime and then have a library parse text at runtime according to the grammar? I'm not sure what you'd have this grammar library return, I'm assuming you'd want some tokens and grammar identification.

I haven't used it, but you may want to take a look at : http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/

Comment: Isn't gold parser fed with text grammar and generates code? I haven't used it for long time but I think it has some template providers that generates code according to grammar.